# Get the count of the rows of text files in a folder

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a folder which is populated daily with txt files. Their names are unknown prior to the copy. 
What I want to do is to get a count of the rows for each of the files present.

e.g. C:\FOLDER\
contains 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt.

I would like something that would give me the filename and the row count into one single file.

Comment: Show us what you tried (If you did)

Comment: Sorry, i thought the requested language is `PHP`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I am doing so in the suggestions bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Powershell with a hash table:

```
$counts = @{}
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem C:\FOLDER)
 { get-content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
   foreach { $counts[$file] += $_.count}
 }

 $counts
```

Comment: That seems to be working fine thank you. Any ideas on how this could also be displaying a message/warning if the row count of a file is more than a specific number?

Comment: @user3459320 I've submitted an answer with warnings for line count above a given number ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/22645757/478656 ).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a batch way of doing it

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=0
set "out=output.txt"
if exist %out% del /q %out%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
    for /f %%b in ('type "%%a"^|find /v /c ""') do (
      set /a cnt=%%b & >>%out% echo(%%~nxa : %%b
    )
)
```

copy the above code into a file called whatever.cmd and run it from the directory where your files are.

Comment: Hi thanks, Tried what you suggested and got the following error. find: unable to access "": The system cannot find the file specified.
find: unable to access "/v": The system cannot find the file specified.
find: unable to access "/c": The system cannot find the file specified.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Comment: try it now. I fixed a few things.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
(
  for %%a in ("c:\folder\*.txt") do for /f %%b in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%%~fa"') do echo(%%~nxa %%b
) > "c:\somewhere\outputfile.log"
```

For each file in list, count its lines and output to log file the name and the count of lines

Or for a faster version, as the `find` command is only executed once

```
( 
   for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('find /c /v "" "c:\folder\*.txt"') do @echo(%%b
)>"c:\somewhere\outputfile.log"
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.I got an error. I tried this and I get that %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @user3459320, in command line the `for` command replaceable parameters use only one percent sign (`for %a in`). In batch files this percent sign needs to be escaped (`for %%a in`)

Comment: Right, I created a batch file where I copied and paste your first bit of code by changing the paths to the ones that I am using. I got the following errors. find: unable to access "/c": The system cannot find the file specified.
find: unable to access "/v": The system cannot find the file specified.
find: unable to access "": The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @user3459320, i don´t know what you changed. If i copy, paste and change paths, it don't gives the indicated errors. What else have you changed?

Comment: I created a folder with the name folder in C: and I put 3 dummy text files in there with some rows. The following is the one that I am using in the file called count.cmd @echo off
(
  for %%a in ("c:\folder\*.txt") do for /f %%b in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%%~fa"') do echo(%%~nxa %%b
) > "c:\folder\outputfile.log" I got the errors that I posted in my previous post. The file outputfile.log is created but it is empty.

Comment: @user3459320 "c:\folder\\*.txt" (missing backslash)

Comment: @user3459320, anyway, i am unable to get the indicated errors. The only way to get them is to have some kind of `find` alternative in the path. Please try to change in code `find` with `"%systemroot%\system32\find.exe"`

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) I tried the following @echo off
(
  for %%a in ("c:\folder\*.txt") do for /f %%b in ('"%systemroot%\system32\find.exe" /c /v "" ^<"%%~fa"') do echo(%%~nxa %%b
) > "c:\folder\outputfile.log" and got 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @user3459320, can you please confirm you have a environment variable called `%systemroot%` that points to your windows installation folder, and that in that folder is a `system32` folder and that folder holds a `find.exe` executable?

Comment: @user3459320, and please, run the previous command without the double quotes in find path (and no, it is new to me, i have never seen it).

Comment: Yep there is one. And the find.exe is in the system32 folder. If I type find in the cmd I get Usage: find directory...expression

Answer (score 1):

Here's a powershell solution:

```
$x = 0
$logfile = "$env:temp\MyLog.txt"
$files = get-childitem c:\
foreach($file in $files)
 {
  $x++
  "File: $($file.name) Count: $x FullPath: $($file.fullname)" | out-file $logfile -Append
 }
```

Oops, edited to include outputting the information into a log file.

Comment: I got the following PS C:\folder> foreach($file in $files) {$x++ "File: $($file.name) Count: $x FullPath: $($file.fullname)" | out-file $logfile -Append}
Unexpected token 'File: $($file.name) Count: $x FullPath: $($file.fullname)' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:91
+ foreach($file in $files) {$x++ "File: $($file.name) Count: $x FullPath: $($file.fullname)" <<<<  | out-file $logfile -Append}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (File: $($file.n...$file.fullname):String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Hmm, I tested this and it worked just fine for me... Are you sure you copied and pasted the entire contents of my post?  From $x to the last } ?  Also, you may want to change the line: ``$files = get-childitem c:\`` to the actual path that you would prefer.

Comment: Did exactly this. If I execute it like .\powershell.ps1 I get an empty outputfile.log. While if I execute it line by line I get the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Long version:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'd:\*.txt'

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $lineCount = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    Write-Output "File $($file.Name) has $lineCount lines"
    if ($lineCount -gt 50) {
        Write-Warning "Warning $($file.Name) is too big"
    }
}
```

(If you redirect to a file, the warnings don't go to the file).

Squished version (no warning):

```
gci *.txt | %{ write "$_ has $((gc -LiteralPath $_ | measure).Count) lines";  }
```

Squished version (with warning, no good for outputting to a file):

```
gci *.txt | %{ $c=(gc -LiteralPath $_ | measure).Count; $w="Write"; if ($c -gt 50) { $w+="-Warning" }; &$w "$_ has $c lines" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\Folder\
ls | % { 
    $c = (gc $_).Count; 
    Write-Output ($_.Name.PadRight(40) + "Count: " + $c) } > C:\logs\lines.log
```